# How to send params value as json array

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, kotlin, retrofit

I have to pass request params value for signup api and value should be pass in this fromat. as i am getting volley error 400. Can anyone help how to resolve.

**Json**

```
{
    "number":"12345678",
    "password":"12345678",
    "first_name":"abc",
    "last_name":"xyz",
    "email":"abc@gmail.com"
}
```

also have to pass content-type and authentication in header

```
fun signup(requestp:String,number: String, password: String, firstname: String,lastname: String,email: String) {





    showDialog()
    var strReq: StringRequest
    val urlapireq= APIReqParam()
    val urlresult = URLCollection()
    var st:Boolean




        pDialog.setMessage("Signing...")
        showDialog()

        strReq= object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URLCollection.obj.BASE_URL,object : Response.Listener<String> {

            override fun onResponse(response: String) {
                println("Change Password Response" + response.toString())
                hideDialog()
                try {

                    val responseObj = JSONObject(response)


                    // Parsing json object response
                    // response will be a json object

                    val status = responseObj.getString(urlapireq.STATUS)
                    val message = responseObj.getString(urlapireq.MESSAGE)
                    val success = responseObj.getString(urlapireq.SUCCESS)
                    val error = responseObj.getString(urlapireq.ERROR)
                    val responsecode = responseObj.getString(urlapireq.RESPONSECODE)
                    if (responsecode == "200") {
                       Toast.makeText(applicationContext,success,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    println("Request for SMS error : " + e.message)
                    /*Boast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "Request for SMS error : " + e.getMessage(),
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

                }


            }
        }, object : Response.ErrorListener {

            override fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError) {
                System.out.println("Change Password: " + error.message)

                /*Boast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration Error: "+
                   error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

            }
        }) {



            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                //Creating HashMap
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put(urlapireq.REQUEST, "signup")
                params.put(urlapireq.Number, number)
                params.put(urlapireq.Password , password)
                params.put(urlapireq.FIRSTNAME , firstname)
                params.put(urlapireq.LASTNAME , lastname)
                params.put(urlapireq.EMAIL , email)
                return params
            }
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json")

                return headers
            }
        }

    println("Verification Url : " + strReq!!)
    // val crashinst=CrashApplicationClass()
    CrashApplicationClass.instance?.addToRequestQueue(strReq,TAG)
}
```

but as it giving me error of

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400.

Comment: What about JsonArrayRequest instead of String request in volley. There is String request, JSONobject request and also JSONArray Request!

Comment: it can help you  https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 0):

check this code as a reference and do according to your code.

```
private void registerUser(){
        final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: { "number":"12345678", "password":"12345678", "first_name":"abc", "last_name":"xyz", "email":"abc@gmail.com" }

Comment: it is in json format only like key and value. here `KEY_USERNAME` is key and `username` is value

Comment: yes, i want to pass as json array form not in key- value pairs

Comment: then how you want pass json array

Comment: "object_update_params":"{\"first_name\":\"abc \",\"last_name\":\"xyz\"}", i want to parse my json string with this escape character and i am unable to parse my value in params with this object update params parameter

Answer (score 0):

try using Json request instead of using String request

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject({

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: actually i tried it before some time then i move to string request

Comment: in that case the only possible answer would be that you are sending bad request ....since you are getting 400 as error code..please check the keys and the url once again..